# Image Collage Maker App

Tags: gratis, android

I'm looking for an Android app for combining several images into one, collage-like. *This is less a question of finding such an app at all - the availability is overwhelming - but rather about identifying one that is a good match for my requirements.*

**Required Features:**

- combining any number (say, at least between 2 and 15) of images
- no malicious/disruptive/intrusive ads (i.e. banners that take up some screen real estate in the app are okay, but full-screen popups in the app that easily get clicked accidentally, or ads that show up outside of the app, are not)
- local processing on the device, i.e. no cloud service in the background, and purely based upon locally stored image files
- if images get cropped, control over which part of the image is used
- control over resulting resolution (or loss thereof)
- resulting image gets saved to the device
- at least some layouts where the total area of the resulting collage is fully covered by the individual images (maybe except for thin seams between the images)
- minimum set of rights required for the features (presumably, nothing besides read/write access to local storage)

**Nice to Have:**

- non-rectangular layouts
- customization of inner layout border colours
- optional freehand marking/highlighting
- no ads
- some way to create or use custom layouts

**Not Required:**

- stickers or other clipart-like overlays
- image editing such as brightness or colour saturation features
- elaborate letterhead-style backgrounds to place images on
- direct camera access
- face recognition or other selfie-enhancement features
- connection to any image hosting service or the like

For the sake of this question, features only available as in-app purchases should be considered as not included in the app (and should in turn not require any permissions that are not required for the basic features, anyway).